# Como faço para executar uma função apos o término de outra?

Tags: javascript

O meu objetivo era executar uma função de cada vez, porém as minhas funções que mexem o quadrado estão sendo executadas juntas e não sei como fazer uma ser executada só depois que a outra termina Aqui está o código:

css:

```
#caixa1{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background: green;
            position: relative;   
        }
        #caixa2{
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background: red;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="caixa1"> 
        <div id="caixa2">


        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

javascript:

```
var posH = 0
        var posL = 0
        var caixinha = document.getElementById("caixa2")
        var intervaloL = setInterval(movL,10)
        var intervaloH = setInterval(movH,10)
        //left = ir pro lado direito
        //top = vai pra baixo
        function movL()
        {
            if(posL >= 150)
            {
                caixinha.style.left = posL +'px'
            }else{
                posL += 1
                caixinha.style.left = posL + "PX"
            }
        }
        function movH()
        {
            if(posH >= 150)
            {
                caixinha.style.top = posL +'px'
            }else{
                posH += 1
                caixinha.style.top = posH + 'px'
            }
        }
```

Comment: Não deu pra entender não. O que pretende fazer?

Comment: eu não entendi o que vc quer fazer, mas de uma olhada em callback

Comment: eu quero executar uma função de cada vez,desculpe se não deu pra entender a mensagem :/

Comment: dei uma editada espere que de para entender dessa vez,novamente desculpe :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só usar clearInterval() nas variáveis criadas com setInterval e depois chamar a outra função quando a primeira terminar. Neste caso, umas das variáveis do setInterval deve ser declarada antecipadamente, conforme mostra abaixo:

```js
var posH = 0
var posL = 0
var caixinha = document.getElementById("caixa2")
var intervaloH = setInterval(movH,10); // chama a primeira função
var intervaloL; // declara a variável a ser usada posteriormente
//left = ir pro lado direito
//top = vai pra baixo
function movL()
{
   if(posL >= 150)
   {
       caixinha.style.left = posL +'px'
       clearInterval(intervaloL); // cancela o segundo SetInterval

   }else{
       posL += 1
       caixinha.style.left = posL + "px"
   }
}
function movH()
{
   if(posH >= 150)
   {
       caixinha.style.top = posH +'px'
       clearInterval(intervaloH); // cancela o primeiro SetInterval
       intervaloL = setInterval(movL,10); // chama a segunda função
   }else{
       posH += 1
       caixinha.style.top = posH + 'px'
   }
}
```

```css
#caixa1{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: green;
   position: relative;   
}
#caixa2{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: red;
   position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="caixa1"> 
  <div id="caixa2">


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok ,obrigado pela ajuda sam